# How to calculate the average of the first 7 observations per individual in a data frame

Tags: r, time-series, average

I have a data frame structured like this

```r
>data
  ID  Location Sex   Time  Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4  Var5  Var6
   12     A     M     .1    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   12     A     M     .2    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   12     A     M     .3    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   12     A     M     .4    …      …     …     …     …     …
   12     A     M     .5    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   12     A     M     .6    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   234    A     M     .1    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   234    A     M     .2    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   234    A     M     .3    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   234    A     M     .4    …      …     …     …     …     … 
   234    A     M     .5    …      …     …     …     …     …
```

There are several hundred individuals, each having a unique `ID` number. The data for each individual is time series data. In the real data, there are several hundred measurements per individual. For instance in the example above there are only 6 observations for individual 12, and 5 observations for individual 234. In reality individual 12 may have 980 observations and individual 234 may have 1249 observations.

How can I get R to return a data frame with the average of the first 7 observations for each individual in this format:

```r
ID  Location  Sex  Variable  Average
12     A        M      Var1     … 
12     A        M      Var2     … 
12     A        M      Var3     … 
12     A        M      Var4     … 
12     A        M      Var5     … 
12     A        M      Var6     … 
234    A        M      Var1     … 
234    A        M      Var2     … 
234    A        M      Var3     … 
234    A        M      Var4     … 
234    A        M      Var5     … 
234    A        M      Var6     …
```

And how can I do the same thing for the last 7 observations for each individual (remember the time series for each individual is of different length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you should be able to pivot your `data.frame` to have all your observations in a single column, filter for top 7 for time for each ID and variable, and take the mean.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(readr) ## just to read OP's data

df <- readr::read_table("  ID   Location Sex   Time  Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4  Var5  Var6
   12     A     M     .1    a      a     a     a     a     a 
   12     A     M     .2    a      a     a     a     a     a 
   12     A     M     .3    a      a     a     a     a     a 
   12     A     M     .4    a      a     a     a     a     a
   12     A     M     .5    a      a     a     a     a     a 
   12     A     M     .6    a      a     a     a     a     a 
   234    A     M     .1    a      a     a     a     a     a 
   234    A     M     .2    a      a     a     a     a     a 
   234    A     M     .3    a      a     a     a     a     a 
   234    A     M     .4    a      a     a     a     a     a 
   234    A     M     .5    a      a     a     a     a     a ") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains("Var")), ~runif(11))

df %>%
  pivot_longer(contains("Var"), names_to = "Variable") %>%
  group_by(ID, Location, Sex, Variable) %>%
  top_n(7, desc(Time)) %>%
  summarize(Average = mean(value))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 5
#> # Groups:   ID, Location, Sex [2]
#>       ID Location Sex   Variable Average
#>    <dbl> <chr>    <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
#>  1    12 A        M     Var1       0.356
#>  2    12 A        M     Var2       0.528
#>  3    12 A        M     Var3       0.489
#>  4    12 A        M     Var4       0.613
#>  5    12 A        M     Var5       0.557
#>  6    12 A        M     Var6       0.730
#>  7   234 A        M     Var1       0.365
#>  8   234 A        M     Var2       0.557
#>  9   234 A        M     Var3       0.580
#> 10   234 A        M     Var4       0.626
#> 11   234 A        M     Var5       0.344
#> 12   234 A        M     Var6       0.534
```

And to do for the last 7, all you have to do is change the line of `top_n(7, desc(Time)` to `top_n(7, Time)` so it arranges highest value to lowest.

Comment: in my real data set, the variable columns are not `Var1:6`. How would I change this code if they were (in order): Cast, Pint, LoR, Cal, Ping, and YeAn

Comment: You can change your call to `pivot_longer` to be `pivot_longer(Cast:YeAn, names_to = "Variable")`.

Comment: you grouped the data by ID using `group_by(ID, Location, Sex, Variable)`, and included `Location`,  `Sex`, and `Variable` in that line so that they would be kept and returned (in that order) In the output. Am I correct? If I had several other columns of categorical variables that I would like to return In addition, how would i do this without typing them all out?

Comment: Correct. Typing them out is the best way in this context. Or you can just join the two `data.frame` together later.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `aggregate/reshape` approach.

```
res <- reshape(aggregate(. ~ id + location + sex, data=dat, function(x) 
  mean(x[1:7]))[-4], varying=4:9, idvar=1:3, direction="long", sep="")
res[order(res$id), ]  # just a little order
#            id location sex time         var
# 12.A.M.1   12        A   M    1  0.23035482
# 12.A.M.2   12        A   M    2  0.67700690
# 12.A.M.3   12        A   M    3  0.12926876
# 12.A.M.4   12        A   M    4  0.06464387
# 12.A.M.5   12        A   M    5 -0.39031674
# 12.A.M.6   12        A   M    6 -0.21768911
# 234.A.M.1 234        A   M    1  0.17089758
# 234.A.M.2 234        A   M    2 -0.09195034
# 234.A.M.3 234        A   M    3  0.40042572
# 234.A.M.4 234        A   M    4  0.23404603
# 234.A.M.5 234        A   M    5  0.08176435
# 234.A.M.6 234        A   M    6  0.02859807
```

Or using `by`

```
do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$id, function(x) {
    cbind(x[1:6, 1:3], var=names(x[5:10]), mn=colMeans(x[1:7, 5:10]))
}))
#         id location sex  var          mn
# 12.1    12        A   M var1  0.23035482
# 12.3    12        A   M var2  0.67700690
# 12.5    12        A   M var3  0.12926876
# 12.7    12        A   M var4  0.06464387
# 12.9    12        A   M var5 -0.39031674
# 12.11   12        A   M var6 -0.21768911
# 234.2  234        A   M var1  0.17089758
# 234.4  234        A   M var2 -0.09195034
# 234.6  234        A   M var3  0.40042572
# 234.8  234        A   M var4  0.23404603
# 234.10 234        A   M var5  0.08176435
# 234.12 234        A   M var6  0.02859807
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- expand.grid(id=c(12, 234), location="A", sex="M", time=(1:20)/10)
dat <- cbind(dat, matrix(rnorm(240), 40, 6, dimnames=list(NULL, paste0("var", 1:6))))
dat <- dat[order(dat$id), ]
```